# insertion into a simple single linked list

Tags: go, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to solve leetcode problem in Go to teach myself the language. I have a single linked list and an insert function:

```
type ListNode struct {
    Val int
    Next * ListNode
}


func Insert(listNode * ListNode, i int) {
    // @fixme how to check the first node?
    if listNode == nil {
        listNode.Val = i
        listNode.Next = nil
    } else {
        for;;
        listNode = listNode.Next {
            if listNode.Next == nil {
                listNode.Next = & ListNode {
                    i, nil
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    vals: = [] int {
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        }
    var list ListNode
    for _,
    i: = range vals {
        Insert( & list, i)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when an instance of ListNode is instantiated the struct fields have zero values and I am unable update the set first element of the list because I am unable to check for it. In other words, that a ListNode item is initialized but empty. So when I  want build a list  `1->2->3->4->5` I end up having: `0->1 ->2 ...5` .  The limitation is that I cannot change the struct definition as leetcode have that already defined. 
Here is a working example of the code above:
https://play.golang.org/p/bIz-VjY1PS7

Comment: You can make `Val` a pointer that would have a zero value of `nil`, or you can treat the first node just as the list head, and not store anything in there, it's called a Sentinel Node https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node

Comment: I cannot change the struct. I can work with zero-valued node being the very first element but I am just curious to see if it's possible to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is that you shouldn't use `ListNode` you should be using `*ListNode`, that way an empty list is represented by a `nil` `*ListNode`:

```
func New() *ListNode {
    return nil
}

func Insert(listNode *ListNode, i int) *ListNode {
    // If it's nil, create it
    if listNode == nil {
        listNode = &ListNode{i, nil}
    } else {
        l := listNode
        for ; l.Next != nil; l = l.Next {
        }
        l.Next = &ListNode{i, nil}
    }
    return listNode
}
```

Comment: More compact version, if you want to have some fun with pointers to pointers =P: https://play.golang.org/p/iEBSbktDH8W

Comment: thank you. With this insert function the actaual listNode passed won't be modified but rather returning a new one, correct? (passed by value)? Could it be modified to passed by reference

Comment: Not if you want it to be able to receive a nil pointer. Because everything gets passes by value, we cannot Point listNode to the new value because what we get is a copy of listNode that gets deleted on return. And because the value is nil, we can't save the new node in the same address, because the memory hasn't been allocated. You can use the approach of leaving the first node as an empty node, and then when you finish working withe the list just do list = list.Next and you will get the list without the extra node at the start.